Facing Issue while sending utxo from one address to another
I need your help regarding Demeter different Era's problem.
I'm running my Node and Workload on demeter.run in preproduction but while sending transaction from one address to another i'm having error like node is running on convay era and workload is running on babbage era. I'm attaching error below thank you:
abc@parallel-broccoli-kwr2o9-0:~/workspace/repo$ ./01-simple-send.sh
Command failed: transaction build  Error: Transactions can only be produced in the same era as the node. Requested era: Babbage, node era: Conway.
Error building transaction

